# Stream from one REST API as response to client Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a vendor rest API which we get significant amounts of json data back.  We can't have our customers accessing this API directly, so what we have done is created our own REST API (C# WebAPI) that takes in the request from our customer clients.

Our Web API then manipulates the data, and makes a request to the vendor rest API along with the required credentials.

We do not do any manipulation of the data that is returned from the vendor API.

I want to return the same stream that is returned from the vendor's REST API, but I do not want to wait until the stream has closed.  As soon as we start receiving data from the vendor REST API call, I want that same data to then be returned to the client caller from our REST API.

This will provide a huge performance benefit and greatly reduce costs of scaling.

Client ------Calls Our REST API----> {OUR REST API} -------Calls Vendor REST API ------> {Vendor's REST API}

How could we accomplish something like this in C#?

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]SearchQuery queryParam)
        {
            string apiKey = _configuration.GetValue<string>("VendorAPIKey");
string restUrl = "https://vendorresturl.com/api/search?kajhfjhsdf";

            var hclient = new HttpClient();
            hclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", apiKey);

            var responseMessage = await hclient.GetAsync(restUrl.ToString());

            var c = new ContentResult();
            c.ContentType = "application/json";
            c.Content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return c;
    }
```

Comment: Show what code you have already that reads their response ; this seems like a trivial “get the vender response stream and start reading from it, get your own client’s response stream and start writing to it, in a loop” scenario

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward, show some code please.

Comment: Ok.  I've added a code sample.  Here you can see it reads the full response and then sends it back to the client.  The problem is that this is 10X slower than if the client just called our Vendor's REST API directly...  If we could stream back the response as we are getting it we could improve the performance greatly..

Comment: So you want your API to act as "Reverse proxy" essentially with your own credentials. I would suggest off the shelves products like Azure API gateway or AWS API Gateway or APIgee. All this products are relatively cheap && dont have to worry about maintainence & scalability etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change two things in your code:

1) Get this API just once, put this in service that persists this Key a singleton variable. In this way, the controller will do a just request for the first time, after that, the key value will be available in the singleton variable stored.

2) Became your flow complete asynchronous using event callback patterns providing a callback url to after the end of the process a webhook be able to send a result of the process.

Read these articles to help you:

- Asynchronous Work Services, https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-async
- Asynchronous Patterns, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/
- Using Service Bus, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/rabbitmq-event-bus-development-test-environment (you can use Azure Service Bus too, ou Google PubSubService, it is a good Idea)